# Type information lives with objects, not variables in python

Tags: python, variables, memory-management, types

i'm curious to know how why type information is moved to python objects and not available in variable name decalarations? As I know according other statically typed languages, the type declaration helps to initalize memory for those variables by telling the compiler exactly how much memory the variable would require at run time. This helps memory optimization and the biggest reason why we declare variables. However, python being a dynamically typed language, all variables reference objects that get created at run time and thus how does the python complier know how to initlialize memory for the objects referenced by the those variables. Does it handle the memory management at run time? Or is allocation of initial memory for variables not a feature in python?

Comment: isn't python a dynamic language?

Comment: Read [this](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-does-python-manage-memory.htm)

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for responses, but i think i figured it out. Since there is really no such this as primitives in python, nothing actually gets stored on the memory stack thus there is no need for type decalarations in python. Everything happpends on the heap, essentially during run time, just like in any other language.

Comment: As far as CPython is concerned, every object is just a `struct PyObject` somewhere on the heap.